# OpenCV Anaconda Package Binding

Tags: python, anaconda, package, opencv

I'm trying to import non-free libraries (such as SIFT surf SURF) which are not available in Conda packages for opencv 4 but available through compiling  OpenCV source code with OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON flag for both c++ and python and It works perfectly with no virtual environment But i want to use the same compiled libraries within anaconda virtual environment.I have followed the instruction at https://pydeeplearning.com/opencv/install-opencv3-with-anaconda-python3-6-on-ubuntu-18-04/ and some other similar instructions but could't pass through the following error:

```
    Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import cv2                                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>
     94     if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')
     95 
---> 96 bootstrap()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in bootstrap()
     84     if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: replacing cv2 module')
     85     del sys.modules['cv2']
---> 86     import cv2
     87 
     88     try:

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2: undefined symbol: cairo_tag_end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i could finally uses sift and surf in anaconda enviroment:
install the opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python packages using pip package manager by the following command

pip install opencv-contrib-python opencv-python

Finally insted of using sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT.creat() use sift = cv2.xfeatures2d_SIFT()

Answer (score 0):

I come across similar error message when compiling opencv 4.4 with anaconda python3 binding.

It turns out to be caused by mismatch librsvg in the system and libcairo library in anaconda installation.

You can either using LD_PRELOAD=*path_to_the_system_libcairo* python3 .... to run the application. *path_to_the_system_libcairo* can to retreived by *ldd path_to_the_system_librsvg | grep libcairo* command.

**OR**

Go the anaconda folder, move the libcairo files to a **backup** location (just in case).